# VBA Excel - Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem with my workbook. So, when I open the workbook it looks like the picture below.

[image: ERROR]

Then when I click the `Debug` button, the highlighted line is `ActiveWindow.Visible = False`.

Here's the entire code that is located in the `This Workbook`.

```
Option Explicit

Public ws_pw As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False 'Highlighted line
    Splash.Show
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Worksheets("HOME").Activate
    ws_pw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB").Range("B10").value
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.protect password:=ws_pw, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next ws
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "SaveThis"

End Sub
```

My workbook was working yesterday, but when I open it today I keep receiving the error. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: It's objecting to James Blunt ;-)

Comment: The `ActiveWindow` is `Nothing`

Comment: If I run it once it disappears. If I then try to make it visible there is nothing to make visible. Do you need an If Not ActiveWindow Is Nothing test? Better still, use an explicit window name.

Comment: Thank you! It opened again when I put the code `Application.Visible = True`.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this `Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False` instead of `ActiveWindow.Visible = False 'Highlighted line`